# error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components

Am getting this error and multiple others about binding like this
:7:21 - error NG8001: 'app-custom-datepicker' is not a known element
the issue is i a have imported all the required modules in the app.module.ts file.
This has occured after moving components and services generated with angular 8 to angular 14.
Although i have cleaned this components and services one by one i cannot figure out where the error is coming from or the reason the app cannot build.

[image]
[image]

Comment: most probably you are missing importing the module that has these components

Comment: Have imported required modules i dont know why this error "error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'" formsmodule is imported

Comment: is `category-purchases.component.html` in the shared module? Otherwise you should check in which module is being imported and check for FormsModule